# Where can I find good WordPress interview questions and answers?

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone help me to get good WordPress interview questions and answers.
Any link or Resource?

Please reply as I am unable to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ample of question and (great) answers here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=frequent. See for yourself, how many can you answer.

Apart from this, I would add 2 questions:
What is wordpress? What can you not do with wordpress?